# How to test paypal sandbox received payment?

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated classic API of paypal and got response success.

Now, how to test the received payment on paypal sandbox and live ?

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

Login at http://developer.paypal.com.  Then click into Applications and then Sandbox Accounts.  You can create buyer and seller accounts to test with here.